# Horizontal scrolling not enabling

Tags: css, html, scrollbar

I have a div that is populated via an AJAX request.  My css is listed below:

```
.ps_content_frame{
  height: 250px;
  margin: 1px 0px 1px 0px; 
  border: 1px solid gray;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: white !important;
}
```

EDIT* I was able to get the horizontal scrollbar to show up, however, it shows up directly below the last line pulled from the ajax request (sometimes in the middle of the div).  How do i dock the scrollbar to the bottom of the container?

Comment: You're saying the horizontal scroller never shows up when text overflows off the right of the screen? like overflow x?

Comment: correct.  I found that issue though.  Bonehead mistake on my part, but now i have a different issue.  Please read above

Comment: could you provide a screenshot? when you say the horizontal bar is 'sometimes in the middle of the div' are you sure the div hasn't just autoresized?

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/StDQu/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/StDQu/1/) has no vertical scrollbar but does scroll y. This is correct. You will never have a vertical scrollbar because of your `nowrap` property.

Comment: What browser are you using? I can't duplicate the issue in FF, Chrome, Opera or IE7+.

Comment: In chrome and IE

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2eg65fp&s=7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, the div was inheriting height from another class.  where height was set to auto and marked as !important.

Answer (score 0):

Try `overflow:scroll;`

http://jsfiddle.net/StDQu/

Comment: I do not want it to always be enabled though

Answer (score 0):

Does the DIV with the class "ps_content_frame" have a width assigned to it?

If not, I don't think that the horizontal scroll bars will appear.

Here is some test code:

```
<div class="ps_content_frame">
    <div class="fixedwidth">asdasd</div>
</div>

.ps_content_frame{
  height: 250px;
  margin: 1px 0px 1px 0px; 
  border: 1px solid gray;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: white !important;
  /* width:400px; uncomment me*/
}

.fixedwidth
{
    width:500px;
}
```

Here is the [example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cW3jz/1/)